# Change color of dialog android

Tags: android, dialog

I'm working with Android Dialog

[image]

I want to remove two black color in this dialog. But seem I can not do it.

This is my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/color_loading_background_white">
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:hint="Enter username" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my code when create dialog.

```
public static void showDialog(Activity activity, int layout, final IOnOkClicked cb, final IOnCancelClicked cb2) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(layout, null))
            // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    if (cb != null) {
                        cb.onClick();
                    }
                }
            })
            .setCancelable(false);

    if (cb2 != null) {
        builder.setNegativeButton(activity.getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                cb2.onClick();
            }
        });
    }
    builder.create().show();

}
```

Please give me advice to do this. Thank you!

Comment: Try to set the background transparent and design your dialog as like you want yourcustomdialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
    new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

Comment: I already set it, but it not change the color

Comment: Oh, in that case did you try to set dialog theme as android.R.style.Theme_Light

Comment: @QuangTV: Y don't u create a custom dialog layout and set it to AlertDialog

Comment: @Madhu When I use R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light. It seem OK but It is not a dialog.

Comment: @kevz I add layout to dialog, am I wrong something ?

Comment: @QuangTV ... Please check my edited solution..

Comment: @QuangTV: true u added the layout but then u have also used +ve and -ve  btns. Define them in that custom layout itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these lines of code to remove the border

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Or use these Simple line of code for it

```
 AlertDialog alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The second answer is good. I try the first but it not change

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exitdialog, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();


        alertDialog.show();
        alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(
                android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: Thank you, but i can not change color

Answer (score 0):

Try any one way from below

give transparent to dialog

```
public static void showDialog(Activity activity, int layout, final IOnOkClicked cb, final IOnCancelClicked cb2) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(layout, null))
            // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    if (cb != null) {
                        cb.onClick();
                    }
                }
            })
            .setCancelable(false);

    if (cb2 != null) {
        builder.setNegativeButton(activity.getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                cb2.onClick();
            }
        });
    }
 final AlertDialog dialog= dialogBuilder.create();
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();

}
```

**2)**  by applying style to dialog

```
<style name="DialogTransparentStyle">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Add style to instance of  alertdialog builder

```
AlertDialog.Builder(activity,R.style.DialogTransparentStyle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this link that will Help You.

http://web.archive.org/web/20120203153326/http://blog.androgames.net/10/custom-android-dialog/